# .NET/C# Drizzle database client

Tags: c#, sql, mono, dblinq, drizzle

I am planning to use [Drizzle](https://launchpad.net/drizzle) in my next C# [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) app.  Since there is no C# client available for Drizzle, I thought I would have a stab at writing my own by converting the [Java client](https://launchpad.net/drizzle-jdbc), and then making it work with [DBLinq](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/).

Having seen the Java client, I realise that it's a longer job that I had anticipated, and I don't have the time.  Besides the Java client is not all that mature yet.

Since there is an official Drizzle C client library ([libdrizzle](https://launchpad.net/libdrizzle)), writing a C# wrapper might be the best solution.  Are there any tools available that can assist in generating the code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also have a look at the [drizzle-interface project](https://launchpad.net/drizzle-interface) on Launchpad.

Within that project, SWIG is used to generate wrappers for various languages such as Python and Ruby. All the SWIG related files are part of that project so it might be worth having a look there. Might make what you are trying to achieve a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, Drizzle speaks the MySQL protocol, so most MySQL clients should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) is very helpful when it comes to automatically generating .Net wrappers for C libraries, you should definitely try it first.